# How should I carry out simple oracle queries from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, data-access-layer

I have the need to carry out a few thousand inserts into an oracle database from a C# program. What would be the best way to carry this out? I need the ability to control transactions and run queries and stored procedures. I don't have a need for a full blown ORM and guess I really just want a simple, stable DAL to run queries. Can anyone suggest such a framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at following oracle data provider for .NET

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

or else, you can look at OLEDB for Oracle.

Comment: Thanks, extra info on why to use Oracle's provider from another SO question .."Oracle has it's own ADO.NET provider for .NET now, and you should use that one instead of System.Data.OracleClient, because MS is not maintaining the System.Data.OracleClient code anymore."